# JBoss 7.x profiling: which profiler to use and how to set up

Tags: jboss7.x

I need to profile our web application that's running on JBoss 7.1.1, so I started out by looking on the internet for examples of how this is done. To my surprise all information I found was a couple years old and related to older versions of JBoss. I did try some of these anyhow, but nothing worked, except for VisualVM. Problem with VVM was the performance. The system became completely irresponsive and as such, unusable.
Does anyone have experience with profiling JBoss 7? Which profiler works? Doesn't need to be a free tool. I'm willing to buy a profiler. But I first need to see it working. Any example setups would be welcome.